# Unable to start zookeeper, pid not found

Tags: apache-zookeeper, pid

I'm getting this error when i check zookeeper status with:

```
systemctl status zookeeper-server.service -l

PID 12684 read from file /var/run/zookeeper/zookeeper-server.pid does not exist or is a zombie.
Failed to start LSB: ZooKeeper is a centralized service for maintaining configuration information, naming, providing distributed synchronization, and providing group services..
```

I checked inside of that directory and I don't see any pid file inside, i guess when you install zookeeper or when you do the init it should automatically write the pid file in there? but for some reason is not happening.

Any idea about what could be my issue? I'm thinking about permission issues but I don't get any error related to not having access to write in that directory.

Comment: now I see the pid file in that directory after the installation but still fails with the same error. (I tried changing the permissions of the file  to 777, and still nothing)